# In WPF, how to add an element to a panel in code-behind, and put it before the last existing element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` and I dynamically add images to it. The `StackPanel` has a `Button` at the bottom, and I want the images to be **above** the `Button`.

**How it works currently:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button />

    <!-- Images are added here -->
</StackPanel>
```

**How I want it to work:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Images are added here -->

    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you may be adding arbitrary number of elements, do it with an ObservableCollection, an ItemsControl, and a DataTemplate. If there will only be one element, put it in the XAML at design time and control its Visibility with a Style or ControlTemplate trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more child stackpanel to which add the images.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
    <!-- Images are added here -->
    </StackPanel>
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Cool. Don't know why I didn't thought about this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
int index = Stack.Children.Count - 1;
Stack.Children.Insert(index, image);
```

Then your button is always the last item. It won't matter how many items are in the StackPanel.

Comment: Great Idea but I like @CarbineCoder more. Thanks A lot!

Answer (score 1):

Give your stack panel a name (e.g. myPanel)then in your codebehind try this;

```
myPanel.Children.Insert(0, myNewControl);
```

The 0 indicates the element within the stackpanel's children, so you could put it where-ever you liked, but obviously 0 is the first element.

Comment: Great Idea but I like @CarbineCoder more. Thanks A lot!